What is the legal basis for Brazil freezing starlink assets due to twitter/x fines?
It looks like Twitter may soon be banned in Brazil due to it's removal of it's legal representative from the country, which in turn traces back to an earlier fight over Twitter refusing to suspend accounts and remove tweets require by Brazil.
Recently Brazil also frozen starlink assets due to the fines twitter owes.
I understand the legal issues with twitter, why it owes fines and may be suspended.  What I don't understand is why a judge in Brazil is allowed to sanction a different company due to twitter's actions.  I realize Musk is connected to both companies, but it doesn't seem like that would be enough basis for punishing one company for another companies behaviors.  Musk owns 54% of starlink, which means 46% of the company is owned by people who would be penalized for twitter's behavior despite having no say in twitter's actions.
So I'm wondering what the legal basis is for the freezing of starlink's assets as a result of twitter's fines.

I am reading that he controls 42% of the stock and 79% of the voting power of space x which owns starlink. https://www.axios.com/2024/08/29/brazil-starlink-x-shutdown

Why the downvotes? Seems like a reasonable question to me

In that case, the court is evoking Article 139 of the Civil Code that gives the judicial branch powers to deal with contempt of court. That article reads:

Art. 139. The judge shall conduct the proceedings in accordance with the provisions of this Code, and it is incumbent upon the judge to:
(...)
III - prevent or suppress any act contrary to the dignity of justice and dismiss merely dilatory motions;
IV - order all inductive, coercive, mandatory, or subrogatory measures necessary to ensure compliance with a court order, including in actions that involve pecuniary obligations;

As you can see, the law gives the judge broad discretion to enforce compliance with their orders.
In the specific case involving X, the judge is claiming that in order to compel X to comply, assets of all companies of the economic group headed by Elon Musk must be frozen. One of the reasons is that X's bank accounts are holding much less cash than expected. Of course, whether this is a reasonable thing to do is being disputed by Starlink. In fact, all the information I gave in this answer can be read from a recent decision in a Starlink's appeal (in Portuguese, Starlink's arguments were dismissed).

Associated entities
australia
While the specifics used of what exactly is an associated entity are Australian, the concept of holding all associated entities responsible for the actions of one of them is pretty universal.
At its core, the concept depends on the associates being able to act as one. That is, the legal or de facto structure is such that they can act with a common purpose - that they have a common ‘mind’ in control.
For this example, the connection is straightforward. Elon Musk is in a position to exercise control of both companies, therefore, the law can treat them as associated and hold one responsible for the wrongdoing of the other.

And if you look at what Musk does with his companies (such as reassigning Tesla employees to work at Twitter), it sure looks like they're simply subdivisions of "Musk, Inc."

Is it fair to penalise the innocent employees and shareholders of the associated companies? I hope the same thing isn't allowed to happen in US

@user768421 yes, it happens in the US. What do  the shareholders and the employees have to do with it - the legal entity is the company.

@DaleM: "The legal entity is the company" - isn't the point here that the legal entity is a group of companies ?! In particular, a group of companies where Musk is a director and shareholder?

@user768421 If you become shareholder of a company, it’s your responsibility if the company may be liable for massive damages, works in an area that loses money, or is exposed to liability for the bad behaviour of the majority shareholder. If I was badly injured by an Amazon delivery van, do you think it’s unfair if I sue them because it hurts the shareholders?

SpaceX and Twitter are legally separate entities, apart from being owned mostly by Elon Musk. Does sharing a major shareholder makes one company somehow liable for the actions of another company owned by the same major shareholder? It's like making someone liable for the criminal actions of his brother because they have the same parent. This is the part that I don't understand.

@gnasher729, if you're badly injured by an Amazon delivery van, it's reasonable for Amazon shareholders and staff to be hurt if Amazon is sued. But it doesn't look reasonable to punish Bezo's other companies which have no relationship with Amazon apart from Bezos being the majority shareholder.

@user768421, in the case of Elon Musk's companies, it's more than just being owned by the same majority shareholder.  As I noted in my earlier comment, Elon Musk treats his companies as a single entity, moving personnel, assets, and possibly money between them as needed.  It's more like making someone's left hand liable for the actions of the right hand.

@user768421 Other Bezos owned companies wouldnt suffer because Amazon has money, and management in the UK where I live, and they are going to pay. I don’t know how closely related other Bezos companies are, but if Amazon came up with excuses not to pay, and hid its assets from bailiffs, they might be at risk. It’s not a legal difference, just the fact that Bezos seems to be a reasonable person.
